# Can't use oracle associative array in object (for custom aggregate function)

Tags: oracle

Background : My purpose is to write an aggregate function in oracle to make a string contains number of occurrence of each element. For example "Jake:2-Tom:3-Jim:5" should means 2 times occurrence for Jake, 3 times for Tom and 5 times for Jim. So for writing a custom aggregate function I should write an object implements ODCIAggregate routines. And also a Map like data structure for counting each element occurrences. Only Map like data structure in oracle is associative array.

Problem : Unfortunately I can't know any approach to use associative arrays in object. I tried these approaches:

1 – Create a generic type for associative array and use it in object. Oracle doesn't let creating generic associative array types.

```
CREATE TYPE STR_MAP IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY VARCHAR2(100);
```

This get following error :

```
PLS-00355: use of pl/sql table not allowed in this context
```

2 – Create map like type in a package and use it in object. Oracle lets creating an associative array in a package, but doesn’t let using an 'in package type' in object. I checked all issues about grant execute on package or make a synonym for 'in package type'. But there is no way for use 'in package type' in object declaration.

**P.S. 1 :**

Of course we can do it for one column by nested group by. But I prefer to do it for many columns with only agg-func. It is very useful agg-func and I wonder why nobody wrote something like this before. For many columns we have limited number of distinct values, and with such an agg-func we can simply summarize all of them. For example if we had such a agg-func named ocur_count(), we can simply analyze an collection of transactions like this :

```
select ocur_count(trans_type), ocur_count(trans_state), ocur_count(response_code), ocur_count(something_status) from transaction;
```

Comment: associative arrays are pl/sql constructs.  Why do you need it exactly, not clear what you're trying to do with the custom aggregate function (give an example of the input and expected output)

Comment: Aggregate function gives a list of strings (for example). The list has repetitive elements. I want to count number of occurrences of each one. For example for a table of transactions, we have limited number of response codes. I wand an aggregate function that operate on response code column and summarize number of occurrences of each element. For example create a result such as "succ:23-unsucc:12-timeout:5". For this purpose I need a map or hash-table like data structure. Something that finding key value doesn’t need searching entire list.

Comment: You're over complicating things I think.  Why not just use [listagg](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) with a group by (see aggregate example).  If thats what you want, I'll put it in an answer, let me know

Comment: listagg concat all repeated values (for example results "succ,succ,unsucc,succ,unsucc,…"). I used wm_concat() with 'distinct' and this gave me only distinct values. But I want to calculate number of distinct values (for example for input "succ,succ,unsucc,succ,unsucc", I want agg-func results "succ:3-unsucc:2"). I wonder that we can't use any data type like map or hash-table inside an object? This is very amazing weakness in oracle.

Comment: I'll give you an example, need to get coffee first ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use listagg and a simple group by with a count to get what you need (Note the listagg output is limited in size to 4k chars).  Here I'm counting occurrences of first names, using ',' as the separator between names and ':' as the separator for count:

```
SQL> create table person_test
(
person_id number,
first_name varchar2(50),
last_name varchar2(50)
)
Table created.
SQL> insert into person_test values (1, 'Joe', 'Blow')
1 row created.
SQL> insert into person_test values (2, 'Joe', 'Smith')
1 row created.
SQL> insert into person_test values (3, 'Joe', 'Jones')
1 row created.
SQL> insert into person_test values (4, 'Frank', 'Rizzo')
1 row created.
SQL> insert into person_test values (4, 'Frank', 'Jones')
1 row created.
SQL> insert into person_test values (5, 'Betty', 'Boop')
1 row created.
SQL> commit
Commit complete.
SQL> -- get list of first names and counts into single string
SQL> --
SQL> -- NOTE: Beware of size limitations of listagg (4k chars if
SQL> -- used as a SQL statement I believe)
SQL> --
SQL> select listagg(person_count, ',')
within group(order by person_count) as person_agg
from (
    select first_name || ':' || count(1) as person_count
    from person_test
    group by first_name
    order by first_name
)

PERSON_AGG                                                                      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Betty:1,Frank:2,Joe:3                                                           
1 row selected.
```

NOTE: If you do run into a problem with string concatenation too long (exceeds listagg size limit), you can choose to return a CLOB using xmlagg:

```
-- this returns a CLOB
select rtrim(xmlagg(xmlelement(e,person_count,',').extract('//text()') order by person_count).GetClobVal(),',')
from (
    select first_name || ':' || count(1) as person_count
    from person_test
    group by first_name
    order by first_name
);
```

Hope that helps

**EDIT**:

If you want counts for multiple columns (firstname and lastname in this example), you can do:

```
select 
typ,
listagg(cnt, ',') within group(order by cnt)
as name_agg
from (
    -- FN=FirstName, LN=LastName
    select 'FN' as typ, first_name || ':' || count(1) as cnt
    from person_test
    group by first_name
    union all
    select 'LN' as typ, last_name || ':' || count(1) as cnt
    from person_test
    group by last_name
)
group by typ;
```

Output:

```
"FN"    "Betty:1,Frank:2,Joe:3"
"LN"    "Blow:1,Boop:1,Jones:2,Rizzo:1,Smith:1"
```

I'd also note that you probably can create a custom aggregate function to do this, I just prefer to stick with built in functionality of SQL first if it can solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion for use of listagg. I describe my situation for use of this approach in p.s. 1 of main question.

Comment: Thanks. This works. But I still have an interest in a simple agg-func for doing it. I can implement something like map or hash-table by myself. But I wondered why oracle doesn’t allow using associative arrays in object.

Comment: Glad it works for you @Hamid .  The reason associative arrays won't work is because they are pl/sql types, not used by the SQL engine directly (similar to trying to implement a boolean type).

Comment: For more, see [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS00501) and note the chart.